# prove a sequence is decreasing after the second term

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that the sequence $a_n=\frac{n+1}{n!}$ is decreasing after the second term.

I thought that if $a_{n+1}<a_n$ then it is decreasing

After some work , 
 $$\frac{n+2}{n+1}<n+1$$

Then im not sure where to go in order to prove this .

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$\frac{n+1}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{n!}.$$

Comment: okay i see , i got 1/(n+1)!<1/(n-1)!  but how did you work this out ?

Comment: $\frac{n+1}{n!} = \frac{n}{n!} + \frac{1}{n!}$

Answer (score 0):

Calculate $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. We have
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+2)/(n+1)!}{(n+1)/n!}=\frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2}.$$

We want to show that $\dfrac{n+2}{(n+1)^2}\lt 1$ if $n\ge 1$. Equivalently, we want to show that $(n+1)^2\gt n+2$. Since $(n+1)^2=n(n+2)+1$, it is clear that $(n+1)^2\gt n+2$ if $n\ge 1$.

Comment: can you tell me the reason for calculating  $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

Comment: We want to show that $a_{n+1}\lt a_n$. (That's what decreasing means.) Since our sequence consists of positive numbers, the inequality $a_{n+1}\lt a_n$ is equivalent to $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\lt 1$ (we divided both sides by $a_n$). In general, there are two sorts of common strategies for showing that $x\lt y$. (i) if $y$ is positive, show that $\frac{x}{y}\lt 1$; (ii) show that $y-x\gt 0$ (that would work nicely here too).